# jquery full calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I am trying to integrate jquery full calendar plugin in my application. But I need to disable the past dates and start selecting dates only from the current dates. How is it possible?? How do I get the start and end dates which I can modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Which "fullcalender" would that exactly be?

If you are using [**jQuery UI datepicker**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max) it has the `minDate` and `maxDate` options which allow you to specify how many days before and after the current date are supposed to be available for selection.

Answer (score 0):

Adam Shaws Full Calendar do not offer this function and i think, it is not easy to implement.

Comment: Yes.. You are right.. I am using Adam Shaws Full Calendar.. But I guess there would be something to initialize such way.. I am not able to figure it out.. Any inputs on this would be highly appreciated

Comment: I guess you could use the dayClick option to check, if the date is in the past. I do not see something else on the fast.

Comment: From the documentation what I understood is that the dayClick option for agendaWeek or agendaDay views.. I need this only in the month views..

Comment: The dayClick works perfectly on the month-view too. I used the following sample code to switch to agendaWeek on dayClick:

dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
   if(view.name == 'month'){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'agendaWeek' )

   }
  },

Answer (score 0):

With Keith Woods date picker

You can set minimum and/or maximum dates within which a date may be chosen. These dates can be set as an absolute date as either a Date or a string (in the current date format). Or they may be set as relative values by using a simple number to offset from today's date a given number of days.

http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

Comment: i am using Adam Shaws Full calendar plugin..http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs. But I am not able to figure it out.. please help

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to do this:

```
var date = new Date();
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    if(start < date) {
        alert('Cannot select past dates.');
        return;
    } 
},
```